# How to read CSV which is in Hindi font using C#.net?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to read data from csv and put that in drop down. This CSV is written in Hindi font (shusha.ttf).

While reading each line I am getting junk values.

```
string sFileName = "C://MyFile.csv";   
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();   
FileStream[] fss = assem.GetFiles();   
if (!File.Exists(sFileName))   
{   
    MessageBox.Show("Items File Not Present");   
    return false;   
}   
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFileName);  
string sItem = null;
bool isFirstLine = true;
do
{
     sItem = sr.ReadLine();
     if (sItem != null)
     {
          string[] arrItems = sItem.Split(',');
          if (!isFirstLine)
          {
               listItems.Add(arrItems[0]);
          }
          isFirstLine = false;
     }

} while (sItem != null);
      return true;
```

Comment: A CSV file can not be written "in a font". It's a character only file. You are talking about encodings, right?

Comment: Yes, this file i wrote in selecting particular font. but when i am trying to read it, it is showing me only English characters. Now i am not able to show these values back to original font. is there any way to show values in drop down using particular font.

Comment: You can not write a CSV file "in a font". A CSV file is just a plain text file. There's no formatting in a text file. Maybe it helps to change the combo box's font?

Comment: @AmitT: there seems to be a very useful answer below that you have forgotten to acknowledge. Since you are still posting here, would you acknowledge it in some way now? A vote, an accept, or a comment are all valid ways of acknowledging helpful assistance.

Comment: Downvoted with regret, see above.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing an encoding paramter to the StreamReader, so it is assuming a default encoding, which is not the encoding the file was written with.

Not all text files or csv files are the same. Encoding systems choose how to convert 'characters' (glyphs, word pictures, letters, whatever) to bytes to store in a computer.

There are many different encoding systems - ASCII, EBDIC, Utf8, Utf16, Utf32, etc.

You need to figure out which encoding the file was written with and pass that as the Encoding parameter to the StreamReader class.

I would have figured that the file was written with UTF8, since it's a pretty universal standard for non-english text; StreamReader's default is to use UTF8 when you don't provide a value, so it is probably not utf8. It's possible it's UTF16, or perhaps even some other completely different encoding.

For the curious who want some background on Unicode - unicode is a standard that assigns simple numbers to glyphs, ranging form ascii to snowmen to mandarin, etc. Unicode just gives each glyph a number, known as a code point. Unicode however is NOT an encoding - it doesn't say how to actually represent those code points as bytes.

UTF8 is a unicode encoding that can cover the entirety of the unicode space, as is UTF16 and UTF32. UTF8 writes 1 byte out for code points below a certain value, 2 bytes for code points below a certain higher value, and so on, and uses signaling bits in each byte to help indicate whether a code point was written using one, two, three, etc bytes.

Internally, for instance, C# represents strings using UTF16, which is why if you look at the raw memory for strings containing only ascii text, you'll see lots of '0' values - ascii doesn't need the other 8 bits, so the values end up being all 0.

Here's a link from wikipedia that explains how UTF8 packs bits from the code point value, with signalling bits, into bytes to store in memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8